# Equation for a Vinyl curve

Tags: plane-curves

This [video](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=926903064004357) seems to show an explicit map from the torus to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does it factorize through the projection $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$? What is the equation of the curve?

Answer (score 0):

These are coupler curves of a *6-bar* mechanism driven by *two* cranks. The *single* crank driven *4-bar* mechanism  generates an Atlas of curves e.g., by Hrones and Nelson. They are derivable by 2D positioned vectors with link constraints.(Mechanical Engineering)